# Which criteria should I use to remove high variable data

Tags: outliers, heteroscedasticity, dispersion

In a biological experiment, I have, for every instance (a gene), three replicates, in a given condition.
Ideally, the three measurements should be very closed from each other. I would like to discard those instances where the three replicates are not consistent, i.e. when there's an outlier, in order to include only reliable instances in subsequent analyses.
My question is then, which metric should I use? A dispersion metric? Or should I rather use an homogeneity test?

Comment: please state the objevtive(s),data type and any other relevant idea.

Comment: I want to include/exclude instances according to their variability (if one instance has three replicates with very different values, it should be discarded). I guess there must be a test for it. The values are numerical.

Comment: are there sets of 3 observations in instance. if so, need not discard any instance. just average each instance and then go for homogeneity test across all instances.

Comment: Every instance (gene) has three observations (replicates), and therefore the values for every instance must be very similar. Otherwise they must be discarded. My question is how to quantify that similarity (homogeneity) within instances (i.e. among replicates).

Comment: what analysis is proposed to be carried out subsequently? if you have a plan to simply weed out outlier data, you may fix / estimate a range for determining good quality data for further analysis. This range may be used as a yardstick. homogeneity test is not desirable for 3 observatios in each instance.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that whatever person or policy is the source of the dictum that non-homogeneous trios "must be discarded" might offer some hint as to how they should be identified.  Without any such guidance, you are faced with an *arbitrary* decision.  There is no single correct answer.  You could simply make up a criterion that you think will be acceptable to your audience.  Perhaps your rule would involve a maximum acceptable standard deviation, or a maximum acceptable range.  Or you could choose from several commonly used tests of outliers, such as Dixon's or Grubbs' (each of which will accommodate samples of size three).